# JavaScript + invalid argument error with fireEvent('onchange')

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Some simple event driven code.  For whatever reason, I can't seem to pass 'onchange' as a parameter to `fireEvent()`.  Throws me an invalid argument error in IE 7/8.  This project needs to be native.  Little help?

**Custom Event Creation:**

```
    createCustomEvent : function(eventName) {
        var evt;
        if(document.createEvent) {
            evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
            evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        }else if(document.createEventObject) {
            evt = document.createEventObject();
            evt.eventName = eventName;
        }
        return evt;
    },
    dispatchCustomEvent : function (el, evt) {
        if(el.dispatchEvent) {
            el.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }else if(el.fireEvent) {
            console.log('on'+evt.eventName); //onchange
            el.fireEvent('on'+evt.eventName, evt);
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
dispatchCustomEvent(element, createCustomEvent('change'));
```

Comment: How do you get `el`? And what is the type of `el`?

Comment: Native dom query, the object is type [object HTMLDivElement].

Comment: But `div` does not have `onchange` event, I guess this is why you are not getting this event.

Comment: But it works in all browsers except for ie7/8, shocker I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so according to most docs the *change* event will fire on any element and I quote: 
"The *change* event is fired when an element loses focus and its value changed since gaining focus."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_Event_Reference/change

However, in <= ie8 *onchange* will not fire on any element besides form elements.  This is incredibly lame imo, and makes modern MVC custom event listening and dispatching an issue.

Long story short, in my case I used the *blur* event to capture changes to my div element.  This worked for me as the focus is removed between div element updates.  It's a slideshow application, where two divs pop on and off the stack, left to right depending on the current location.